# How can I write my app with one language and run it on android, iOS, and the web?

Tags: php, android, ios

I need to write my app to 3 languages. I need to have a web version, iOS, and Android version for my app. I wrote an Android version already. I'm looking for a way that I can run apk file on a simulator written in PHP or any way that I can write my code to one language and can run it on Android, iOS and the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking about cross-platform app building approach for all three platforms (i.e *Android*, *IOS* and *Windows*) there are several *SDK* or *IDE*s like **[Phone Gap](http://phonegap.com/)**, **[Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/)**, which allow you to write your code logic once and it will be built for all the three platforms mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for, but I used [IonicFramework](https://ionicframework.com) a while ago, and it's excellent. It allows to export to Android and iOS, but I'm unsure about the web.
I'd recommend taking a look at it.

I also don't recommend using the same code for both Web and Mobile applications.

Answer (score 1):

Simply. You can't run an APK with php. However, if you developed that app, it comes with a debugger/emulator.

What are you trying to do here? Don't make life harder than it already is.

And you won't be able to compile things in another language. That's c#, and objective c in which you'll need to learn. Have fun

Answer (score 0):

To me, your procedure is not very clear. There are very nice projects like Unity which allows you for multiplatform development, i.e. build once, deploy everywhere [from their website].

It really depends on the specification of your project whether you can effectively use such frameworks/tools.

https://unity3d.com/unity/multiplatform